# Changing div background colour on refresh

Tags: html, colors, refresh

I am working on a landing page concept. And I want to change the background-colour of a Div on every refresh (with jQuery). And I've tried alot of things but it didn't work.

I am not really experienced with Javascript.

Comment: Set it to a random color is not enough?

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mydivid').css("background-color", getRandomColor());
}

function getRandomColor() { 
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split(''); 
    var color = '#'; 
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) { 
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)]; 
    } 
    return color; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can use a random color on each reload. If you want to ensure the color changes, you can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to remember the previous value.

Example:

```
$(function(){
  var prevColorId = sessionStorage.getKey("colorID"); //undefined if not present
  var colorList = ["lightRed", "lightGreen", "lightBlue" /*, ...*/];
  var nextColorId = prevColorId+1; //NaN if prevColorId undefined
  if(colorList[nextColorId]===undefined){
    nextColorId=0;
  }
  sessionStorage.setKey("colorID");
  $("#myRainbowDiv").css({background: colorList[nextColorId]});
}
```